# How to get add to cart url in custom product collection?

Tags: magento-1.7, product-list, custom, shopping-cart

I created a custom collection using below code.

```
<?php 
        $catNum = 19; //The number of the category you want to load
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catNum);
        $products_best = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->setPagesize(6);

        foreach ($products_best as $_product_best){
        $productt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product_best->getId());
            $urlll = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($productt);
            echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product_best, $_product_best->getName(), 'name')."<br>";

             echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product_best, true)."<br>";
             ?>

             <img class="image" style="opacity: 1;" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product_best, 'small_image')->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(336,157); ?>" 
                     alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product_best, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"><br>
             <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $urlll; ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Carts') ?></span></span></button>
             <?php
        }
?>
```

When i click add to cart button in the checkout page the message said that "**product was added to your shopping cart**" but below section there is nothing added to the card(shoppincart.png).
How can i fix this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$key =  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
```

add key in url

```
onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>checkout/cart/add/product/<?php echo $productt->getid();?>','form_key/<?php echo $key; ?>')"
```

Comment: Thank you, This method not working.Once i add this code left side layered navigation is not working.

Comment: update the answer try this it is working tested code..